# put textbox content on span or li after doing space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

Is there an easy way to do something like the tag editor at the bottom of the question area in stackoverflow.
I need a list of strings. So, I planned to do a textbox and on pressing the space key, the content is pushed in to a span or a li tag, and the textbox is emptied and ready to enter new content to be pushed.

Comment: I don't need autocomplete. I have tried with a textbox and an empy ul before, then on each space event, I get the content from the textbox, add it to a li in the ul, clear the textbox. but there are problems with the size of the resulting textbox, so I was wondering if there is not an easier implementation (like in stackoverflow, with spans ?)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "there are problems with the size of the resulting textbox"? What kind of problems?

Comment: the textbox is smaller when there are many li, so I don't know how to handle it cleanly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/swFuX/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="tags"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
border: 1px solid #FF7800;
padding:10px 0 10px 5px;
}

#tags{
 border:none;
}
.mytag{
background:#FF7800;
color:#fff;
padding:5px;
margin-right:5px;    
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#tags").keyup(function(event) {
  //alert(event.keyCode);
    if(event.keyCode=='32'){
        var tagname= $(this).val();
        if(tagname!=" "){
            var newtag= $("<span class='mytag'>"+tagname+"</span>");
            $(this).before(newtag);
        }
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/swFuX/2/) I hope you wanted this behaviour

Comment: yes it is the correct behaviour, I've done something like this, but I had problems with the words with space like "Los Angeles", so I do an autocomplete in the textbox, and catch the click event instead of the space, then I can select expressions with multiple words.